# How to group rows in Excel while taking into account "daisy-chaining"?

Tags: excel, grouping

I have some data in an excel sheet that looks something like below:

| ID | Group |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 1 |
| B | 2 |
| C | 2 |
| D | 3 |

Each group says that all IDs in that group are related to one another. Notice that, through B, A and C are related to each other despite being in separate groups. A and C are "daisy-chained" together through B. I want to find all groups, taking into account daisy-chaining, in this data set. The ideal output table would look like below:

| ID | Super-Group |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1,2 |
| B | 1,2 |
| C | 1,2 |
| D | 3 |

I've tried working this problem through power query but I could only get so far on my minimal experience. From what I could garner online, I should be able to get the result I want through some clever joining but I can't wrap my head around the logistics of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you just ask the logic, so I will just propose one way to do it, and I trust you can find out the correct Excel formulae or Power Query to implement it yourself.

Assuming group data look like below:

[image: groups by ID]

First step would be grouping IDs by Group Number:

[image: grouped by groupNum]

The formula I used here is `FILTER()` and `TRANSPOSE()`

The next step would be finding out common IDs for different combinations of group pairs.

Below table means B is in both Group1 and Group2, E is in both Group2 and Group3, E is in both Group2 and Group4, D,E are in both Group3 and Group4.

[image: combinations of group pairs]

So following group pairs have daisy chain between them:
(1,2) (2,3) (2,4), (3,4).

The formula I used to find out common elements between two groups is this:
[extract common values from two lists in excel](https://exceljet.net/formulas/extract-common-values-from-two-lists)

[image: extract common values from two lists in excel]

The final step is to list all GroupIds for group pairs that have "daisy chain" between them.

[image: display results]

e.g, since (1,2) has daisy chain between them, we can use `FILTER()` or `XLOOKUP()` to find out all GroupIds that are in Group1 or Group2.

Comment: Does this method work for datasets that have IDs in more than two groups?

Comment: I updated the screenshot in my answer. E is in group 2, 3, 4. Some IDs will show up in more than one super-groups. Not sure if that is what you want.